# Concatenating a string and a variable within curly braces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I concatenate a string and a variable within `{}`? E.g.
`onClick={this."social"+key}`:

```
                    <Button
                    onClick={this.'social'+key}
                      color="transparent"
                      justIcon
                      key={key}
                      className={classes.customButtonClass}
                    >
```

Comment: can you explain what's the point of concatenation in click handler?

Comment: Is that a function name you're trying to concatenate?

Comment: i have made array which maps with parameter key from which i can create functions

Comment: yes i am going build function with that name

Comment: You can also provide alternative to this

Comment: do you have `this.social0`,`this.social1`,`this.social2`... like functions?

Comment: Yes i have function social0,this.social1,this.social2

Comment: This doesn't look very ideal. Maybe instead of social0,1,2 functions, you could have one function that receives the key parameter as a number and does something with it? so you could call them onclick like this.social(key).

Comment: `onClick={this['social'+key]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store those functions in an array and can use that array in `onClick`,

```
render() {
    const fns = [this.social0, this.social1, this.social2, this.social3]
    return (
      <div>
        {buttons.map((btn, key) => {
          return (
            <button onClick={fns[key]} key={key}>
              {btn}
            </button>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-kuczu?fontsize=14)